# Show all uploading files in Tabular format with progress Circle

Tags: reactjs, mongoose

I am using the Formik Field Array property for file upload with data and showing those data in a tabular format with a progress bar/circle. I am using a state to save the data fetching from for loop and want to show those selected files in a table but after setting those data I am only getting single File of the last selected file of Field array. Why am I not getting all selected files?

```
 const [VideoStatus, setVideoStatus] = React.useState(false);
 const [fileData, setFileData] = React.useState([])
 const handleAddVideo = async (values) => {
        try {
            for (let i = 0; i < values.videos.length; i++) {
                setFileData(values.videos[i])
                console.log("Forloop  - ", fileData);
            }
            console.log("fileData - ", fileData);

            await values.videos.map(async (data) => {
                const formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('serial', data.serial)
                formData.append('title', data.title)
                formData.append('fileName', data.fileName);
                formData.append('teacher_id', data.teacher_id);
                formData.append('description', data.description);
                formData.append('date', data.date);
                formData.append("courseId", courseId);
                formData.append("moduleId", moduleId);
                formData.append("videStatus", radio);
                visible = {visible}
                setVideoStatus(true);

                // Calling the Route
                let response = await axios.post(`${ConfigData.SERVER_URL}/admin/video/videoupload`, formData,
                    {
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                        },
                        onUploadProgress: data => {
                            //Set the progress value to show the progress bar
                            setProgress(Math.round((100 * data.loaded) / data.total))
                        },
                        withCredentials: true
                    })

                if (response.data.status == false) {
                    throw Error(response.data.message)
                }
                else {
                    // If Success Change the Status to Updated
                    console.log("*****Success*****");
                }
            })
        }
        catch (e) {
            // If Error Change the Status to False
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
```

```
    {
                    fileData &&
                        VideoStatus ?
                        <Table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">Sr No.</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Video Name</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Size</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Status</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
    
                                {
                                    fileData ?
                                        <>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>{incrementindex + 1}</td>
                                                <td>{fileData.fileName.name}</td>
                                                <td>{fileData.fileName.size}</td>
                                                <td> 

    {progress ?
                                                                                    
                                                       <ProgressBar now= 
                                                     {progress} label={`${progress}%`} />
                                                                                : null
                                                                            }</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </> : console.log("Nothing")
    
    
                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </Table> : null
    
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

If fileData state variable is type of array you can use with using map or flatmap to iterate over its fields and values.

In code block of table you can use the code as

```
{
  fileData.map((element, index)=>{
     return <>
             <tr> 
               ...
             </tr>
     <> 
  })
...
```

Comment: After setting data to fileData i am getting empty array but before setting data in logs I am getting data. so I can't map fileData to show in other table. I am confused.

Comment: You can conditionally check if the having length more than 0 then you can render element using map function in the view section.